# Is calling a small function twice (e.g. in if condition and body) preferable to storing result in a local variable?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, coding-style, code-readability

Which of the two options below is better (or preferable), and why?

```
ReturnType *function1(const ParamType *param) {
  const ValueType* value = getSomeValue(param);
  if (value) {
     return value->finalStuff();
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

VS

```
ReturnType *function2(const ParamType *param) {
  if (getSomeValue(param)) {
     return getSomeValue(param)->finalStuff();
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Given ***getSomeValue*** like :

```
ValueType * getSomeValue(const ParamType *param) {
    if (param) {
        return param->some.very.boring.stuff.value;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: Try both, check the generated code for each. And don't forget to enable optimizations when building.

Comment: Option 3 (requires C++17): `if (const ValueType* value = getSomeValue(param); value) {
     return value->finalStuff();
  }`

Comment: they have different meanings. Is it possible that the returned value changed between the calls? (think multithreading) Do you need the updated value on the second call? Or do you rather need consistency between the two calls? only after answering this I would turn to performance, is the call expensive?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica: Before C++17, you can even do `if (const ValueType* value = getSomeValue(param)) { return value->finalStuff(); }`

Comment: In your case, I would only work with reference, removing the need of check ;)

Comment: Indeed, option 1 could even be shortened by declaring the value in the if condition since value not used outside the if block (not sure if it's a + or - for readability :). Anyway, I guess the possible overhead (for the local variable usage) remain the same ?

Comment: @Jarod42 : Reference could be a good option, but difficult to deal with optional attributes ^^ unless defining some kind of empty value for each custom  type ?

Comment: No yet *continuation* for `std::optional` (as proposed `.then`)... You an still add your own (as free function).

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of looking like an opinion (and of recapping the comments): use the variable declaration.  It better expresses the intent: get **a** pointer and use **it** if **it** is not null.  It’s surely no more expensive (the pointer lives in a register!) and might be much less expensive if `getSomeValue` is (or becomes) at all complicated.  If `getSomeValue` has side effects, or if other threads might change the value it returns, you also avoid the issue of the second call **differing** from the first (read: being null when the first wasn’t).

You can avoid repeating `value` by declaring it in the `if`:

```
ReturnType *function1(const ParamType *param) {
  if (const ValueType* const value = getSomeValue(param)) {
     return value->finalStuff();
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged [performance](/questions/tagged/performance), it depends whether `getSomeValue()` is inlined or not, and whether calling `getSomeValue()` has observable effects (which includes any synchronization, like accessing a mutex, atomic variable, etc.).

In your particular case though, clang, GCC and VC++ generate identical code ([Link to godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dvqJh-)):

```
getSomeValue(ParamType const*):           # @getSomeValue(ParamType const*)
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB0_1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
function1(ParamType const*):               # @function1(ParamType const*)
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB1_1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB1_3
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rax]
        ret
.LBB1_1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.LBB1_3:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
function2(ParamType const*):               # @function2(ParamType const*)
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB2_1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB2_3
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rax]
        ret
.LBB2_1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.LBB2_3:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

<sub>(GCC generates `function2` as `jmp function1`, but otherwise identical code when only one of the two functions is defined)</sub>

So it comes down to personal preference / code readability really.

Answer (score 1):

*better* is subjective and might refer to performance issue, readability or code maintenance.

---

**PERFORMANCE**

Your function `getSomeValue` does not have any side effects and is candidate to [pure](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) attribute :

> Calls to functions that have no observable effects on the state of the program other than to return a value may lend themselves to optimizations such as common subexpression elimination. Declaring such functions with the **pure** attribute allows GCC to avoid emitting some calls in repeated invocations of the function with the same argument values.
>
> The pure attribute prohibits a function from modifying the state of the program that is observable by means other than inspecting the function’s return value. However, functions declared with the pure attribute can safely read any non-volatile objects, and modify the value of objects in a way that does not affect their return value or the observable state of the program.
>
> For example,
>
> `int hash (char *) __attribute__ ((pure));`
>
> tells GCC that subsequent calls to the function hash with the same string can **be replaced by the result of the first call** provided the state of the program observable by hash, including the contents of the array itself, does not change in between. [...]
>
> Some common examples of pure functions are **strlen** or **memcmp**.

As a result, calling twice `getSomeValue(param)` in your second example will not perform worse than storing the return value thanks to optimization.

---

**READABILITY**

The answer depends on how your function and your variable are named. For a general advice, write as less code as possible and provide only explicit and useful information.

In your first example, your variable `value` does not add any useful information to the program. I prefer your second approach because calling `getSomeValue(param)` indicates clearly a **getter** returning a property from the specified parameter. A **getter** can be called repeatedly in the code without problem, this is common in object oriented programming for example.

Your first example might be better if you put additional information to the return value.

---

**MAINTENANCE**

Your first example does not add more useful information than the second while containing 1 more variable and 1 more line of code, which leads to clutter and more code maintenance.

---

**CONCLUSION**

Your two examples are equivalent in term of performance if you add [pure](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) attribute to your function `getSomeValue`. IMHO your second example is shorter and so better.

Answer (score 1):

When I read the second variant, I instinctively wonder whether the function is really stateless, and really guaranteed to yield the same result when it's called a second time. This is a mental pothole. Even more so when the function takes more (complex) arguments, which I would also need to check individually to determine whether the two calls can be expected to yield the same result.

By contrast, the first variant calls the function once, checks the result, and leaves zero doubt that `value` won't be a null pointer when the call to `value->finalStuff()` is made.

So, even though the first variant uses one more variable (more syntactic complexity), it's simpler to reason about than the second variant. And the later is what really matters, imho.

---

Concerning performance, the first variant is guaranteed to be at least as fast as the second one, as caching a pointer in a CPU register is always faster than calling a function. The second function call is always pure overhead if the compiler cannot optimize it away. This may be possible if the function's definition is known to the compiler, but may be impossible if it is implemented within another translation unit.

---

Finally I second [Davis Herring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626915/2445184): The syntax to move the variable declaration into the `if()` condition has specifically been designed to facilitate this use case. Use this tool where appropriate, which is the case for the code in question.